QGIS Radial Flow map: How can I move a centroid point to the middle of a country?
How can I move a centroid to a centre of a country in the QGIS world map and doing a Radial Flow map as described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEHMnioynN8
As I understand

You create centroids via processing/toolbox/centroids
Then save as a separate centroids layer in the lower box with three dots
Then move centroid with right click on centroids.shp
Click toggle editing
Click the now freshly activated vertex tool button with screwdriver and hammer
Move mouse to circles on map and drag mid-points to country center
Save edits via yellow pencil button

But - when I do no. 6 it doesn't work. Centroid points stay where they are...

Hello Vince, I don't understand what you wanted to say ... Could you please clarify?
